# Securely using password as bash argument

Tags: security, bash

I'm extracting a part of a web application that handles the signup, the other part will be rewritten.

The idea is the signup part can exist as a separate application, interface with the rest of the application for creating and setting up the account. Obviously there are a ton of ways to do this, most of them network based solutions like SOAP, but I'd like to use a simpler solution: a setup script.

The concern is that certain sensitive data, specifically the admin password of the new account, would be passed through bash.

I was thinking of sharing a small class between the applications, so that the password can be passed already hashed, but I would also have to pass the salt, so it still seems like a (small) security risk. One of the concerns is bash logging (can I disable that for a single command?) but I'm sure there are other concerns as well?

This would be on the same private server, so the risk seems minimal, but I don't want to take any chances whatsoever.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the salt in clear is no problem (the salt is usually stored in clear), the purpose of the salt is avoiding the same password hashing to the same hash always (so users with the same password would have the same hash, and rainbow tables would only need a single hash for each possible password).

What is more problematic is passing sensitive data through command line arguments, an eavesdropper on the same box can see the arguments to any command (on Linux they appear on /proc//cmdline, and on most Unixes can be seen using `ps`; some systems restrict permissions on /proc// to only the `owner` of the process for security).

What you could do is pass the sensitive information through a file, don't forget to set the `umask` to a very restrictive setting before creating the file.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Ok, thought about it, tried it: throwing it in a file after setting umask 022 works for me. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I have an issue with this. The signup application is PHP. According to the manual umask can cause issues because it is not thread safe. I'm trying to understand what issues it could have in this specific situation. In the sense of what files could get the restrictive permissions that need more...

Comment: Meh, I'll just test my ass off. Thanks again.

Comment: `umask 022` is too permissive. PHP's umask documentation has a couple of insightful comments: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php#100198 (for security default to closed, then open as necessary), and  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php#75459 (attack scenarios). Also, you may want to use dio_open (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dio-open.php) instead of fiddling with umask (from open(2) manpage: the permissions of the created file are (mode & ~umask)).

Comment: I ment 0077 of course, sorry. I did read those comments, which made me confident this would work. What dould the advantage of dio_open() be?

Comment: dio_open() allows to specify the file permissions when creating a new file.

Answer (score 2):

Use the $HISTFILE environment variable, unset it (this is for all users):

```
echo "unset HISTFILE" >> /etc/profile
```

Then set it back again.

More info on $HISTFILE variable here: http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/histfileenviron.htm

Hope this helps!

Comment: Turns out you can also clear the current session history by issuing "history -c". I'll have to try this out, very interesting. Even more info here: http://www.foogazi.com/2008/06/25/how-to-delete-bash-history/

Comment: Thanks, that helps with logging part.

Comment: So I could start the script by running "history -c" and the execution of that script would not be logged, right (and anything else in the session but it would generally be a one-command session)?

Comment: "history -c" wipes the existing history for the current session. This means that you should "history -c" after executing the script.

Comment: xxx@xxx:~$ call it
-bash: call: command not found
xxx@xxx:~$ history
    1  history
    2  call it
    3  history
xxx@xxx:~$ history -c
xxx@xxx:~$ history
    1  history
xxx@xxx:~$

Comment: So the command is added to the history in RAM, AFTER it is executed?

Comment: history -c wipes out the commands entered for the current session (not sure from where the RAM or the history file, doesn't really matter, since no commands will go into the log file for the session). If you end the session before doing history -c, then the log file will contain the bash commands.

Comment: It's easy to try it out and experiment with it. "history" will get you the bash log for the current session. You can also tail the log itself to make sure that history is actually bash history.

Answer (score 2):

From the man page of `bash`:

> **HISTIGNORE**
>                 A  colon-separated list of patterns used to decide which
>   command
>                 lines should be saved on the  history  list.   Each  pattern 
>   is
>                 anchored  at  the  beginning of the line and must match
>   the com-
>                 plete line (no implicit  ‘*’  is  appended).   Each  pattern 
>   is
>                 tested  against  the line after the checks specified by
>   HISTCONTROL are applied.  In  addition  to  the  normal  shell 
>   pattern
>                 matching characters, ‘&’ matches the previous history line. 
>   ‘&’
>                 may be escaped using  a  backslash;  the  backslash  is 
>   removed
>                 before attempting a match.  The second and subsequent
>   lines of a
>                 multi-line compound command are not tested, and are added
>   to the
>                 history regardless of the value of HISTIGNORE.

Or, based on your comment, you could store the password in a protected file, then read from it.

Comment: I'd like it to be somewhat portable though, at least I wouldn't want the command to be logged even if the system config somehow got reverted to do the logging anyway, and exporting the variable in the script itself would be too late, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Bash doesn't normally log commands executed in scripts, but only in interactive sessions (depending on appropriate settings). To show this, use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "-- shopt --"
    shopt | grep -i hist
echo "-- set --"
    set -o | grep -i hist
echo "--vars --"
    for v in ${!HIST*}
    do
        echo "$v=${!v}"
    done
```

Run it like this:

```
$ ./histshow
```

and compare the output to that from sourcing it like this:

```
$ . ./histshow
```

In the first case take note that `HISTFILE` is not set and that the `set` option `history` is `off`. In the second case, sourcing the script runs it in your interactive session and shows what your settings are for it.

I was only able to make a script keep an in-memory history by doing `set -o history` within the script and to log its history to a file by also setting `HISTFILE` and then doing an explicit `history -w`.